# In MVC, is the database part of the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, model

In RoR with relationships being defined in the model, does this imply that the DB itself is part of the model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database (or any data store, in a more generic sense outside of standard use of the Ruby On Rails framework) is the persistence in which models are kept in storage.

Think of the models as "active" things which interact and respond to commands and exhibit behavior consistent with business logic.  If a model needs to be made "inactive" (to conserve memory, or because it's no longer logically in the scope of what's happening, etc.) then data which represents the attributes of the model is persisted to a data store.

Note the difference.  The model (or entity) *itself* isn't persisted to the data store.  *Attributes* which *represent* (or describe) the model are persisted to the data store.  Enough information about the model to reconstruct it in its current state at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

No. The model is the object that represent the data, the entities.
[M in MVC](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/03/31/putting-the-m-in-mvc-part-i.aspx)